# How can I remove duplicates in an array without using `uniq`?

Tags: ruby

The object of my coding exercise is to get rid of duplicates in an array without using the `uniq` method. Here is my code:

```
numbers = [1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 5]

def my_uniq(array)
  sorted = array.sort
  count = 1
  while count <= sorted.length
    while true
      sorted.delete_if {|i| i = i + count}
      count += 1
    end
  end
  return sorted
end
```

- When I run this, I get an infinite loop. What is wrong?
- Can I use `delete` the way that I am doing with `count`?
- How will it execute? Will `count` continue until the end of the array before the method iterates to the next index?
- I did this with `each` or `map`, and got the same results. What is the best way to do this using `each`, `delete_if`, `map`, or a `while` loop (with a second loop that compares against the first one)?

Comment: I'm not sure why you have 2 while loops.  The inner loop is what is infinite, because `while count <= sorted.length` never gets looked at.

Comment: Your question has been answered. Here's another way: `numbers.each_with_object({}) { |n,h| h.update(n=>:anything) }.keys #=>[1, 4, 2, 3, 5] `. This requires Ruby v1.9+, which keeps hash keys in insertion order. It relies on the fact that hashes have unique keys.

Comment: Thank you for your edit Cary. I am new to SO and am learning the "proper" ways to ask questions. I will try to keep my wording to a minimum ;) and thank you for your answer as well.

Comment: Your approach is not the best because the array is changing in size, but you keep incrementing the index `count`.  Also, the block in `sorted.delete_if {|i| i = i + count}` refers to indexes, but you to compare values.

Comment: That exactly answers some of the concerns I had, but was unsure of! (I am also aware that '=' should be '=='). Thanks Cary!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that the inner loop is an infinite loop:

```
while true
  sorted.delete_if {|i| i = i + count}
  count += 1
end #while
```

you can probably do what you are doing but it's not eliminating duplicates.

one way to do this would be:

```
numbers = [1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 5]
target = []
numbers.each {|x| target << x unless target.include?(x) }
puts target.inspect
```

to add it to the array class:

```
class ::Array
    def my_uniq
       target = []
       self.each {|x| target << x unless target.include?(x) }
       target
    end
end
```

now you can do:

```
numbers = [1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 5]
numbers.my_uniq
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mircea!!! Since i set my count to only go as far as array.length, why is it an infinite loop? is it the placement of the count iterator?  I am playing with your solution now (which is easy to understand - much appreciated for that), as it needs to be a method, and it also needs to be added to the Array Class.

Comment: nope. it's the while true. that means execute while true is true which is forever

Comment: What I have done to it is this:                                                                                                     numbers = [1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 5]

  def my_uniq (array)
  target = []
  array.each {|x| target << x unless target.include?(x) }
  end

  puts target.inspect                                                                                            but I get "undefined local variable or method 'target for main:Object            ....so I am working on that! But again, thanks!!!

Comment: ahhhhhh! the while true! I am going to go back and try to make that work, just for sh!ts and giggles :)

Comment: updated to show how you would add your own method to the array class :)

Comment: ohhh thats very nice Mircea!!! I likey!!!! && (note to self...remember to use 'self' when adding method to a Class. and I already knew that. tuh! lol)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a clearly written example.

```
numbers = [1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 5]

def remove_duplicates(array)
  response = Array.new
  array.each do |number|
     response << number unless response.include?(number)
  end
  return response
end

remove_duplicates(numbers)
```

Comment: I love this answer as well because it is along the lines of one of my many attempts...except it actually works! at least I know my thought process was correct. Again, I would love to upvote this but I don't have the rep yet. Thanks for your input jBeas, it is very easy to see what is happening and another great example to learn from :)

Answer (score 2):

As others pointed out, your inner loop is infinite. Here's a concise solution with no loops:

```
numbers.group_by{|n| n}.keys
```

You can sort it if you want, but this solution doesn't require it.

Comment: Thank you Mark! That is elegant! I don't have the rep yet (I'm a noob) to upvote your addition,  or I would ;)

Answer (score 1):

You count use [`Set`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0//libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) that acts like an array with does not allow duplicates:

```
require 'set'
numbers = [1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 5]

Set.new(numbers).to_a
#=> [1, 4, 2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: @seinna you mean "I haven't heard of the Set class yet."

Comment: oops! true indeed jBeas

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Array#&](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-26) passing the array itself as parameter:

```
x = [1,2,3,3,3]
x & x #=> [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the answer. However, I do not know how much of performance issue it takes to return unique

```
def my_uniq(ints)
    i = 0
    uniq = []

    while i < ints.length
        ints.each do |integers|
            if integers == i
                uniq.push(integers)
            end
            i += 1
        end
    end
    return uniq

end
```